# wrong output Python program

Tags: python

writing code to find out highest number in list

```
import sys

print ("Enter number of elements \n")

i = int(sys.stdin.read())

print ("Enter numbers \n")

input = sys.stdin.read()

numbers = input.split()

print ("Number of elements in list",len(numbers))

if (len(numbers)<=i):

    print ("Valid Inputs \n", len(numbers))

    max_index1=-1

    for x in range(len(numbers)):

        if ((max_index1==-1)or(numbers[x] >= numbers[max_index1])):

            max_index1=x

            print ("max index is",max_index1)

print ("Highest input number is", numbers[max_index1])
```

while executing this code I am getting correct output as below:

```
Enter number of elements

5
Enter numbers

10 45 32 23 21
Number of elements in list 5
Valid Inputs

 5
max index is 0
max index is 1
Highest input number is 45
```

but sometimes the output is totally wrong:

```
Enter number of elements

5
Enter numbers

10 45 32 6 21
Number of elements in list 5
Valid Inputs
 5
max index is 0
max index is 1
max index is 3
Highest input number is 6
```

can someone please help me to fix this code?

Comment: Please, indent your code (with Alt+K, for example).

Comment: Are you aware that `input` is a reserved word, that your code blocks?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use the max function. You can call max on an array of numbers and it will return the largest number.

```
num_array = [5, 3, 6, 12, 3, 5]
largest = max(num_array)
print("Max num: {}".format(largest))
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use int function in your code.

```
int(numbers[x]) >= int(numbers[max_index1]))
```

If you shouldn't, Python compare numbers[x] string and numbers[max_index1]

In dictionary order, "45" is behind "6"

Comment: sure will give this a try, but how typecasting will help here?

Comment: int typecasting makes a string integer. For instance, int("45") became integer 45. If not use int typecasting, you just compare "45" and "6". Therefore, as "4" is smaller than "6" in ascii code, your answer will be wrong. I think you want to compare the integers.

Answer (score 0):

The items in your list are strings, so they are being ordered *lexicographically*:

```
>>> '6' > '45'
True
>>> 6 > 45
False
```

You should convert the items in the list to integer type to do a numerical ordering by replacing:

```
input = sys.stdin.read()
numbers = input.split()
```

With:

```
numbers = [int(i) for i in input().strip().split()] # use 'raw_input' for Python 2
```

That reads the items in using the builtin `input` function, *strips* leading and trailing whitespaces, *splits* the string into a list and converts each item in the list to integer using a *list comprehension*.

Note that using `input` as a name is not a good idea as it *shadows* the builtin `input` function which you should probably be using in place of `sys.stdin.read`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your list `numbers` is a list of strings. To show this, you can print numbers.

```
>>> print(numbers)
['10', '42', '32', '6', '21']
```

In python 2.7, a string can be compared with another string with (possibly) surprising results

```
>>>  '6' > '42'
True
```

To avoid this problem, you can change numbers to be a list of integers

```
>>> numbers = map(int, numbers)
>>> print(numbers)
[10, 42, 32, 6, 21]
```

where `map` allows you to apply a function to each of the elements of numbers and return the result.